# Which Android development blog has the most walkthroughs and tutorials?

Tags: android, blogs

I need to work on my Android development skills.  Which blog has the freshest and most walkthroughs, code samples, and tutorials?

Comment: It might be better to rephrase this as, "where can I find a decent set of tutorials/development guides for Android", so as not to limit to blogs.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are only willing to look at one blog?  You might find that learning from a variety of sources will give you exposure to multiple perspectives on things.

Comment: [Future Studio](https://futurestud.io/blog/tag/android) for all kinds of Android tutorials, like Retrofit, Picasso, Glide & Gson.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> the freshest and most walkthroughs, code samples, and tutorials?

Unfortunately I don't think this is the best approch. Many of these tutorials are a year+ old (when Android was still in its alpha release); a lot has changed in terms of the API and UI conventions.

**Included API Samples**
I recommend being familiar with 1)simply creating a project and then 2)reviewing all the API samples included in your Android dev install. These samples should be in the `\samples\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis` folder of your Android install path.

**Android Tutorials**
About 6 months ago I presented an Android overview at NYU's ITP with a simple hello world tutorial. It details how to get Eclipse and your first app up and running. It can be found here:

- http://perkmobile.com/tutorial_helloworld/Perk%20Mobile%20Android%20Tutorial.html

Also, we provided an mapping tutorial that demonstrates how to use web services in conjunction with Androids mapping control. Most importantly it shows how to safely makes use of background threads for managing HTTP requests.

- http://perkmobile.com/itp.html

Comment: Can not agree enough. The outdated tutorials tripped me up a lot when I first started learning.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to  look at the list of blogs at [planetandroid.org](http://planetandroid.org) the list is on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

Well at least the "official" Android development blog contains pretty recent entries at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2):

Tutorial series for 2D and 3D on [droidnova.com - Android Development](http://www.droidnova.com)

Comment: Depends what you want to develop but if its games I have found droidnova fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a comprehensive introductory tutorial for Android development, please check out my own (Game of Life) tutorial: http://www.quesucede.com/page/show/id/conway_game_of_life_android.

Areas covered include (but not limited to): implementing a custom (orthogonal grid) component, a so-called 'game loop,' and the implementation of and the subsequent interaction with a preferences activity.